Is there an error in how I am attempting to make a FastF1 API call in a Flask app?
Trying to build a simple F1 Flask app built on FastF1 API for my final project of CS50x.
I am trying to return an event schedule when a user selects a year from a dropdown box.
I was able to generate event schedules with the following code, which when I changed the years parameter it successfully generated an event:
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    schedule = fastf1.get_event_schedule(1954, backend='ergast')
    return render_template("schedule.html", tables=[schedule.to_html(classes='data', header="true", index=False)])

However I encounter an issue when I try to implement this with my dropdown box on the home page, sometimes it loads but mostly it does not:
@app.route("/schedule", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def schedule():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = int(request.form.get("year"))
        schedule = fastf1.get_event_schedule(year, backend='ergast')

        return render_template("schedule.html", tables=[schedule.to_html(classes='data', header="true", index=False)])

The traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1498, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/app.py", line 31, in results
    schedule = fastf1.get_event_schedule(year, backend='ergast')
  File "/home/matt7/Documents/coding/Projects/cs50_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastf1/events.py", line 525, in get_event_schedule
    raise ValueError("Failed to load any schedule data.")

I then read around API calls and remembered that actually I should do this using a try/except so I tried the following:
@app.route("/schedule", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = int(request.form.get("year"))
        try:
            schedule = fastf1.get_event_schedule(year, backend='ergast')
            return render_template("schedule.html", tables=[schedule.to_html(classes='data', header="true", index=False)])
        except:
            return render_template("error.html")

This seems to have resolved my problem, but am I actually correct in thinking that this is resolved because of the try/except? I will note that the other change I made was to add import requests - though I haven't actually called this, it was just in the API guide I read.
I need to improve my try/except code a lot, and I'll read around on how to do that, but I may be back with that question in the future!
Thanks,
Matt

The error is telling you that there is no schedule to fetch - so how you want handle that depends on what your application should do - usually you might want to redirect the user to a place to add a schedule event, or you might want to hide the selections that doesn't have events connected to them - and then issue a 404.

That’s what I thought, however I know for a fact that those event schedules exist in the data because the error doesn’t occur when I run it via the /test route. I have limited the drop-down box to years 1950-current, so the input range will only allow requests of relevant and available event schedules. sorry - I should I have specified that.
